# Seeded LDA using topicmodels in R

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I would like to perform a LDA in R by means of topicmodels. To make the resulting topics better match the topics I want to see, I would like to input "seed words" for these topics into the LDA, comparable to what the Python guidedlda package does (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-we-changed-unsupervised-lda-to-semi-supervised-guidedlda-e36a95f3a164).

In the documentation of the topicmodels package, the author writes:

> When Gibbs sampling is used for fitting the model, seed words with
>   their additional weights for the prior parameters can be specified in
>   order to be able to fit seeded topic models.

And, above:

> Optional arguments. For method = "Gibbs" an additional argument
>   seedwords can be specified as a matrix or an object of class
>   "simple_triplet_matrix"; the default is NULL.

My questions:

- Do I understand correctly that topicmodels allows me to do a seeded LDA comparable to the guidedlda package in Python?
- How exactly does it work, how does the code look like here? Do I simply input another argument "seedwords" into LDA() with a matrix containing two columns (word and weight)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An author of the topicmodels package was so friendly to provide a sample code which explains how to do it:

```
library("topicmodels")
data("AssociatedPress", package = "topicmodels")

## We fit 6 topics.
## We specify five seed words for five topics, the sixth topic has no
## seed words.
library("slam")
set.seed(123)
i <- rep(1:5, each = 5)
j <- sample(1:ncol(AssociatedPress), 25)
SeedWeight <- 500 - 0.1
deltaS <- simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v = rep(SeedWeight, 25),
                                nrow = 6, ncol = ncol(AssociatedPress))
set.seed(1000)
ldaS <- LDA(AssociatedPress, k = 6, method = "Gibbs", seedwords = deltaS, 
            control = list(alpha = 0.1, best = TRUE,
                           verbose = 500, burnin = 500, iter = 100, thin = 100, prefix = character()))

apply(deltaS, 1, function(x) which(x == SeedWeight))
apply(posterior(ldaS)$terms, 1, function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5])
```

**EDIT**: The variable j determines the seed words by column number of the simple tripled matrix. In order to feed in your own words, you could do the following:

```
data <- tidy_text %>%
  cast_dtm(paragraph, word, n) # Document term matrix

i <- rep(1:5, each = 2) # Number of topics, number of "seeded" words per topic

seedWords <- c("service", "health",
               "sustainability", "energy", 
               "dialogue", "stakeholder", 
               "car", "mobility", 
               "test", "drive")

# Find the position of your seed words in your DTM
j <- NULL
for (z in seq_along(seedWords)) { # This loop surely can be made more elegant
  j[z] <- which(data$dimnames$Terms %in% seedWords[z]) 
# the final triplet matrix is not allowed to have NAs; thus, make sure 
# first that your seed words actually appear in the DTM
}
```

Comment: I apologize for asking for clarification, but this is the only post that approximates what I've been trying to do using R (guidedlda for Python works fine).
Can anyone explain how I can change this line of code to specify the words? j <- sample(1:ncol(AssociatedPress), 25)
simple_triplet_matrix only accepts integers, and I'm not able to identify the values of j associated with the specific words that I would like to use as seeds.

Comment: Just edited my answer to explain this :)

Comment: Recently, seeded LDA was implemented with `quanteda`: [https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda](https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda)